# Shortcut for differentiating $y=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{a+b\cos(x)}{b+a\cos(x)}\right)$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, derivatives

We are required to differentiate (wrt to x):
$$y=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{a+b\cos(x)}{b+a\cos(x)}\right)$$

---

**Background:**

I know how to solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ manually (simple application of the chain rule of course). But I was told that there's a simpler way to solve this problem, and can't seem to find the shortcut.

For instance, if we are required to differentiate $y=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\right)$, we wouldn't directly start to apply the chain rule; we would, instead, *notice that arctan's argument can be simplified to $\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$*, hence reducing the problem to simply differentiating $\tan^{-1}\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$, i.e. finding the derivative of $\frac{x}{2}$, which is simply 0.5.

{Note: Function is defined for all real nos. where $\cos(x)\neq -1$}

---

To reiterate, I'm just asking whether or not there exist shorter methods to solve the posed problem (involving usage of some trig identity, some substitution, etc etc).

Comment: is this $$arcsin(..)?$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That's right.

Comment: @Kugelblitz I've found some simplification, but I don't know if it's faster than yours. Can I post it and get feedback anyway?

Comment: Sure! No problem

Comment: So far, the intended simplification eludes me, even after cheating: I anti-differentiated the derivative and didn't see anything particularly simple. There are indications that the substitution $a = b \cos c$ could be useful. With this, it's possible to write $$y = \frac{\pi}{2} - 2\tan^{-1}\left(\tan\frac{c}{2}\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ but this won't let you avoid Chain Rule complications when differentiating. I hope that whoever told you there's a simpler way also tells you what that simpler way is; then you can come back here and tell us. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let define

$$h(x)=\cos(x),$$

$$g(x)=\frac{a+bx}{b+ax},$$

$$f(x)=\arcsin(x),$$

and your function

$$y=f(g(h(x))).$$

then

$$y'=f'(g(h(x))).g'(h(x)).h'(x).$$

with

$$f'(X)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-X^2}},$$

$$g'(X)=(\frac{bX+a}{aX+b})'=\frac{b^2-a^2}{(aX+b)^2},$$

and of course

$$h'(x)=-\sin(x).$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: And this doesn't seem to be much simpler.

Comment: This is by the use of chain. OP already knows that.